# How set custom class weights in Detectron2

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I use https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/tutorials/install.html for my dataset with another classes and objects.

And my dataset is unbalanced. I wish set different weights for each class. How can I do that?

Comment: You can check augmentations inside the docs, https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/modules/data_transforms.html#detectron2.data.transforms.AugInput

or if that does not work, just flip those underrepresented classes yourself before inputtung them into the dataloader ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way yet to configure this without [writing your own components](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/write-models.html).

One way to do this quickly would be to write a new head that inherits from the head containing your loss. The loss would then be replaced with a new loss object initialized with your loss weights.

For example in the case of [DeepLabV3+](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/projects/DeepLab/deeplab/semantic_seg.py), this would look like this:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from detectron2.modeling import SEM_SEG_HEADS_REGISTRY
from detectron2.projects.deeplab import DeepLabCE, DeepLabV3PlusHead

@SEM_SEG_HEADS_REGISTRY.register()
class MyNewHead(DeepLabV3PlusHead):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        weight = torch.Tensor([0.4, 0.6])  # Adapt to your case
        if self.loss_type == "cross_entropy":
            self.loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(
                reduction="mean", ignore_index=self.ignore_value, weight=weight
            )
        elif self.loss_type == "hard_pixel_mining":
            self.loss = DeepLabCE(
                ignore_label=self.ignore_value,
                top_k_percent_pixels=0.2,
                weight=weight,
            )
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unexpected loss type: %s" % self.loss_type)
```

Then, you modify your config file to select the new head:

```
MODEL:  
  SEM_SEG_HEAD:
    NAME: "MyNewHead"
```